# External Clipboard Manager breaking in JIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard, copy-paste

I use an external clipboard (ClipMenu) on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with IntelliJ Idea 13.0.3. It works everywhere else, but breaks consistently in JIdea.

Comment: Same problem with PHPStorm 7-9

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently this is due to a Java bug.
See solution from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114252#comment=27-678923 :

> Right click on "Application/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app" choose "Show Package Contents", edit "bin/idea.properties", add this property "ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True", restart intellij.
>
> Using MaxOS 10.9, ClipMenu 0.4.3, Intellij IDEA 13 Ultimate.
>
> Update : This trick will likely hang the UI, "Until given an official ok this is a 'hack' not a 'fix'"

YMMV.

Comment: Just to confirmed this in a tweet:
https://twitter.com/wmacdonald/status/534094657278316545 Working great on Yosemite, PHPStorm and Launchbar which has a built in clipboard manager.

Comment: FYI: originally I accepted @naotaka's answer, however given the number of votes for my own answer which is a more general solution for Clipboard Managers in JIdea, I decided to switch it (even though it seems weird to accept my own answer).

Comment: This also fixes the issue with PHPStorm 7-9

Comment: You rock! This worked beautifully for RubyMine 7. This was killing my productivity since I've become reliant on 3rd party clipboard managers and  recently moved to IntelliJ for my Ruby needs.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the developer of ClipMenu. Recently I found a workaround for this issue, and released a testing version. If you are interested in it, please try it and give me your feedback.

http://www.clipmenu.com/blog/2014/10/31/compatibility-testing-with-jetbrains-ides/

Comment: Upvoting this too just because it's awesome to see core developers responding the stack overflow questions :)